# Z-Index is not working while dragging node

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have a "container" node that is behind the other nodes. I've set the `z-index` to `1` to the container and `10` to all the other nodes. It looks as follows:

[image: ui example]

However, when I **drag** the container, it suddenly gets on top of the others:

[image]

When I release the container it gets back to normal.

Container node stylesheet:

```js
const parentNodeStylesheet: Stylesheet = {
  selector: parentSelector,
  style: {
    width: 280,
    height: 350,
    "z-index": 1,
  },
}
```

One of the inside nodes stylesheet:

```js
const nodeStylesheet: Stylesheet = {
  selector,
  style: {
    label,
    color: 'black',
    'background-color': '#DFDFDF',
    width: 230,
    height: 180,
    "z-index": 10,
  },
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you drag an element, its state will be active. https://js.cytoscape.org/#selectors/state In this state, I observed that their z-index automatically becomes 10.

So I suggest you set the normal z-index to something greater than 10.

```
const nodeStylesheet: Stylesheet = {
  selector,
  style: {
    label,
    color: 'black',
    'background-color': '#DFDFDF',
    width: 230,
    height: 180,
    "z-index": 11,
  },
}
```

If z-indexes of 2 elements are the same, the active element will be rendered on the top.